# How can I pass a JWT from the client side to my API to be properly authenticated?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, axios

I need to pass a JWT with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE methods from my UI to my API.

For this I tried to create a front-end using ReactJS. I get:

> POST http://localhost:4000/book/ 401 (Unauthorized)
>   when I try to send a request.

I know I have to pass my token, which I did via postman when I send data to mongo DB.
I'm new to MERN stack, so I am still trying to understand.

1. This is the book controller

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { book_schema } from '../model/book_model';

const Book = new mongoose.model('Book', book_schema);

export const add_new_book = (req, res) => {
    let new_book = new Book(req.body);

    new_book.save((err, book) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(book);
    });
};
```

2. These are the book routes

```
import {add_new_book} from '../controller/book_controller';
import {authorization} from '../controller/user_controller';

const book_routes = (app) => {

    //GET
    app.route('/book')
        //POST
        .post(authorization,add_new_book);
}
```

3. This is the user controller

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bycrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import { user_schema } from '../model/user_model';

const User = mongoose.model('User', user_schema);

export const register = (req, res) => {
    const new_user = new User(req.body);
    new_user.hash_password = bycrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    new_user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: err
            });
        } else {
            user.hash_password = undefined;
            return res.json(user);
        }
    });
};

export const authenticate = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        user_name: req.body.user_name
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication Failed ! - No User.' })
        } else if (user) {
            if (!user.comparePassword(req.body.password, user.hash_password)) {
                res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication Failed ! - Wrong Password.' })

            } else {
                var token = res.json({
                    token: jwt.sign({ user_name: user.user_name }, 'RESTFULAPIs', { expiresIn: '24h' })
                });
                //$window.sessionStorage.accessToken = response.body.access_token;
                return token;
            }
        }
    });
};

export const authorization = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized User !' })
    }
};

export const de_authenticate = (req, res) => {

};
```

4. This is the server

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
import db_config from './config_db.js';

const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

//import routes here
import book_routes from './api/route/book_route';
import user_routes from './api/route/user_route';
import item_routes from './api/route/item_route';


//mongo DB connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db_config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
    () => { console.log('Database is connected') },
    err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err) }
);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//JWT setup
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'JWT') {
        jsonwebtoken.verify(req.headers.authorization.split(''), [1], 'RESTFULAPIs', (err, decode) => {
            if (err) req.user = undefined;
            req.user = decode;
            //console.log(req.user );
            //console.log(decode);
            next();
        });
    } else {
        req.user = undefined;
        next();
    }
});


//to app
book_routes(app);
user_routes(app);
item_routes(app);


app.get('/', (req, res) =>
    res.send(`Node Server and Express Server Running on Port : ${PORT}`)
);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`Server is running on Port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

I developed front end using ReactJS and import axios for access API via URL. In insert_book.js file my form submission function is look like this,

```
  onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const book_obj = {
            book_no:this.unique_id_generator(),
            isbn_no: this.state.isbn_no,
            author: this.state.author,
            published_year: this.state.published_year,
            publisher: this.state.publisher,
            category:this.state.category
        };
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/book/', book_obj)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
        this.setState({
            isbn_no: '',
            author:'',
            published_year: '',
            publisher: '',
            category:''
        })
    }
```

Lastly I would like to provide user routes code,

```
import {register,
    authenticate,
    authorization
} from '../controller/user_controller';

const user_routes = (app) => {

    //SIGNUP
    app.route('/auth/signup')
        //POST A USER
        .post(register);

    //SIGNIN
    app.route('/auth/signin')
    //AUTHENTICATE USER
    .post(authenticate);
}
export default user_routes;
```

Here are the areas where I am stuck:

1. How could I store these tokens in sessions to send with future requests?
2. How to attach and send token value with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE methods?

Comment: use this to save token in local storage ```res=>localStorage.setItem('token',(res.data.token))```

Answer (score 0):

so to store the token in local storage:

```
const user: User = getUserFromBackend()
// assuming user is an object
localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
// get token
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
```

to make a request with token header:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
```

Comment: could you help me with implementation. because I had problem with handling created token.

Comment: yes it's easy to access if it saved in local storage rather than cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Although late to answer. I'd suggest storing JWT in cookie if possible. Then you just read the cookie and pass JWT in headers for the request where you need authentication. I prefer to call the header key `x-api-token` and set its value to the JWT string.

Moreover, you just need to authenticate the user once from your backend by decrypting this JWT and verifying. Once JWT is verified, you can create a session for authenticated user. This session expires in half hour or whatever you've configured in your App.

This way you don't need to send JWT again as the session is valid. I'm not saying that sending JWT is not good and sometimes required in applications where you don't create a session for authenticated user. This happens when performing operations requiring one time authentications like payment processing.

Implementing this logic shouldn't be a problem using node's JWT-decode package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode).

Hope this helps.